# $[f(x)]^2$ being continuous should not imply that $f(x)$ is continuous

Tags: analysis, epsilon-delta

So intuitively this makes complete sense, as $\forall.x\in \mathbb{R}, [f(x)]^2\geq 0$, however when using $\epsilon-\delta$, I come to a strange conclusion:

$[f(x)]^2$ is continuous so for $c\in \mathbb{R}, \epsilon > 0, \exists.\delta>0$ such that
$$|x-c| < \delta \Rightarrow |[f(x)]^2 - [f(c)]^2| = |f(x) - f(c)||f(x) + f(c)| < \epsilon$$

So, for any $\epsilon_1 > 0$ and $c\in \mathbb{R}$, let $\epsilon_2 := MIN(\epsilon_1, \epsilon_1|f(x) + f(c)|)$.
There exists $\delta_2$ such that
$$|x-c| < \delta_2 \Rightarrow |f(x) - f(c)| < \frac{\epsilon_2}{|f(x) + f(c)|} \leq \epsilon_1$$
And thus for any $c\in\mathbb{R}$ and $\epsilon>0$, there exists $\delta>0$ such that
$$|x-c| < \delta \Rightarrow |f(x) - f(c)| < \epsilon$$
And this would mean that $f(x)$ is continuous. But if
$$\forall. x\geq 0,f(x) = 1 $$
$$\forall. x<0, f(x) = -1$$
$[f(x)]^2$ is continuous, but $f(x)$ is not. Where did this proof go wrong?

Comment: Your $\epsilon_2$ is not well defined since it depends on $x$.

Comment: You have no guarantee that for all $c$ and $x \in B(c, \delta)$ you have $f(x) + f(c) \neq 0$, so dividing by $0$ is probably one of the mistakes you made.

Comment: @Fenris Ahhh, ok I see. Is this the only problem (other than some functions dividing by 0)?

Comment: Your intuition is right that this is an odd conclusion to come to, and here's a counter-example to show it. Let $f(x)=1$ if $x\geq 0$ and $f(x)=-1$ if $x<0$. Then, $f$ is discontinuous at $x=0$ but $[f(x)]^{2}\equiv 1$ which is clearly a continuous function.

Comment: Thou shall not divide by zero!

Comment: @JWP_HTX Please observe that the person asking the question is aware of this and has suggested the exact same counterexample at the end of his post.

Comment: @Fenris oops..read too quickly and didn't see that

Comment: @TiagoC.Botelho Good catch, however there exists functions for which $x\neq y \Rightarrow f(x) \neq -f(y)$ and that are not continious, however $f(x)^2$ is. Look at $f(x) = 2^x$ for $x<0$ and $f(x) = -(2^x)$ for $x\geq 0$.

Comment: @RolandKillian - Tiago C. Botelho still has found where the error Fenris points out becomes a problem. This fails exactly when $f(x_n) \to -f(c)$ for some sequence $x_n \to c$. If $f(x)$ is bounded away from $-f(c)$ for $x$ sufficiently close, then you can use that bound to find an $\epsilon_2$ that works for all such $x$.

Comment: But the question I have for you, is since you had the obvious counter-example, why did you not try your proof on that specific counter-example? Then you would have seen that  $\epsilon_2 :=\min \{\epsilon_1, 0\} \not < 0$ for this function.

Comment: @PaulSinclair This is a good point. I should have done this. So the problem is that such an $\epsilon_2$ does not always exist? The other thing is that for functions such as $f(x) = 2^x$ for $x<0$, and $f(x) = -(2^x)$ for $x\geq0$, $\epsilon_2 := \min\{\epsilon_1, \epsilon_1*z\}$ where $z>0$ always. So $\epsilon_2> 0$ exists, yet $f(x)$ is not continuous.

Comment: Even in that case no $\epsilon_2 > 0$ exists. When a sequence exists $x_n\to c$ exists such that $f(x_n) \to -f(c)$, then $\epsilon_1\cdot|f(x_n) - f(c)| \to 0$ as $x_n \to c$. Repairing the error Fenris points out requires $\epsilon_2$ to be an infimum over all $x$ in some neighborhood of $c$, which will be $0$. So your error is irreparable.